# Unable to pass variable to styling attribute in shiny and htmltemplate

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using shiny but leveraging my own custom CSS and html.  I've encountered an issue where i'm unable to pass a value to my UI from server and place it inside a div tag.

What i'm aiming for is:

```
######all my code#####
<div style="color:{{textOutput("my_variable")}}"
####rest of code####
```

For whatever reason, shiny won't pass the value cleanly and thus my app doesn't load properly.

Here's the full code

```
library(shiny)

test_date <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'))
score <- c(75,80,85,90)
my_dataframe <- data.frame(test_date, score)

getColor <- function(x) {
  if (x > 80) {
    result <- "green"
  }
  else if (x > 50) {
    result <- "yellow"
  }
  else {
    result <- "red"
  }
  return(result)
}

ui <- htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '
  <html>
  <head> 
  {{headContent()}}
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="color:{{textOutput("score_color")}}">{{textOutput("score_value")}}</div>
  </body>
  </html>'
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$score_value <- renderText(
    {mean(my_dataframe$score)}
  )
  output$score_color <- renderText(
    {getColor(mean(my_dataframe$score))}
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So if this was working right, I would see the answer of 82.5 displayed in red text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think shiny is not intended to output pure text. You can build the div in the server and output the UI:

```
library(shiny)

test_date <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'))
score <- c(75,80,85,90)
my_dataframe <- data.frame(test_date, score)

getColor <- function(x) {
  if (x > 80) {
    result <- "green"
  }
  else if (x > 50) {
    result <- "yellow"
  }
  else {
    result <- "red"
  }
  return(result)
}

ui <- htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '
  <html>
  <head> 
  {{headContent()}}
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  {{uiOutput("score_value")}}
  </body>
  </html>'
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$score_value <- renderUI(
    div(
      renderText(
        {mean(my_dataframe$score)}
      ),
      style=paste0('color:',getColor(mean(my_dataframe$score)),';')
    )
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```